# How to get a terminal for output when running a .sh script?

Tags: linux, bash

I am new to Linux. I have a simple .sh file that help me to run an application from a directory.

```
#!/bin/bash

/home/nick/TestApp/app.x86_64
```

when I run the .sh file, I can observed that the console app is running in the background from System Monitor. However, there is no terminal showing up and I could not see the output of the program. How do I get it to work like it was executed from a terminal manually? I want to see the output.

P.S. I am running the .sh from Desktop with double click.

Comment: Does `gnome-terminal -e your_script` or `xterm -e your_script` help?

Comment: oops ... it seems that `-e` is an obsolete flag for `gnome-terminal`, take a look to https://askubuntu.com/questions/1116385/option-e-is-deprecated-and-might-be-removed-in-a-later-version-of-gnome-termi for an alternative.

Comment: Ooh, there's a surprise, gnome breaks standards again. I think it's based in Redmond now.... `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin It's a pity that they give so little importance to backwards compatibility, I recently migrated all my scripts using zenity to xdialog precisely for that reason :(

Comment: Agreed, zenity is an unfortunate casualty of the slow-motion train-wreck that has been Gtk+3 and will only worsen in Gtk4. A far cry from when there was a vibrant community of developers that eagerly awaited the new features with each new release of Gtk+2. What was excitement around a desktop and project has now become a cringe....